# rails doesn't render view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a rails project and I'm stuck because rails doesn't render a view despite in console appeare like rendered.
I have this form in index.html.erb of Trip scaffold

```
<%= form_with(url: filter_path, method: "get") do |form| %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= form.label :from %>
        <%= form.select :from, @places_arr %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= form.label :to %>
        <%= form.select :to, @places_arr %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= form.label :departure_date %>
        <%= form.date_select :dep_date %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= form.label :departure_time %>
        <%= form.text_field :dep_time %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= form.label :price %>
        <%= form.text_field :price %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= form.label :rating %>
        <%= form.text_field :rating %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= form.label :model %>
        <%= form.select :model, @vehicles_arr  %> &nbsp
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= form.label :alimentation %>
        <%= form.select :alimentation, @vehicles_alimentation %>
    </div>
    <div class="btn btn-primary">
        <%= form.button :submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

This is the route that redirect to the action:

```
get 'trips/filter', to: 'trips#filter', as: 'filter'
```

Action "filter" in Controller is actually empty

```
def filter
end
```

I think when I click on "Submit" on form I should be redirected to the view filter.html.erb, but this doesn't happens. Nothing happens.

In console appears this:

```
Started GET "/trips/filter?from=7&to=7&%5Bdep_date(1i)%5D=2021&%5Bdep_date(2i)%5D=11&%5Bdep_date(3i)%5D=23&dep_time=&price=&rating=&model=&alimentation=benzina&button=" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-11-23 19:24:55 +0100
Processing by TripsController#filter as JS
  Parameters: {"from"=>"7", "to"=>"7", "dep_date(1i)"=>"2021", "dep_date(2i)"=>"11", "dep_date(3i)"=>"23", "dep_time"=>"", "price"=>"", "rating"=>"", "model"=>"", "alimentation"=>"benzina", "button"=>""}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:8:in `current_user'
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering trips/filter.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered trips/filter.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 0.0ms | Allocations: 4)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
  Rendered layouts/_flash.html.erb (Duration: 0.0ms | Allocations: 12)
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:8:in `current_user'
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:8:in `current_user'
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:8:in `current_user'
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (Duration: 2.5ms | Allocations: 1458)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 15.0ms | Allocations: 10550)
Completed 200 OK in 18ms (Views: 15.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms | Allocations: 11518)
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to Rails 6.1 `form_with` defaults to `remote: true` and will send an XHR request for JS. You can see that thats what happening from:

```
Processing by TripsController#filter as JS
```

Rails won't actually raise if the `js.erb` template is missing and will just implicitly render the HTML template which is sent back to the browser which does absolutely nothing with it.

If you want to send a normal syncronous request you need to explicitly set it in the form:

```
<%= form_with(url: filter_path, method: "get", local: true) do |form| %>
```

If you want to buy into the whole [Server Side Concerns](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#server-side-concerns) gimmick you need to create a `js.erb` template.

```
# filter.js.erb
document.getElementById("#myid")
        .innerHTML = "<%= j render partial: 'some_partial' %>";
```

However [Rails UJS is (finally) dead as of Rails 7](https://world.hey.com/dhh/rails-7-will-have-three-great-answers-to-javascript-in-2021-8d68191b) so its not a very future proof approach.

Comment: Thank you, now it works! Only a detail: it doesn't work with remote:false, it works with local:true. Don't know why, but it's ok :)

Comment: That's weird - they are supposed to just be the opposite options to each other.

Comment: Ah sorry. I was confused. The `remote` option is for `form_for`. Interesting that they replaced it and choose something even less descriptive.